# What is wrong with Google Maps API?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have an old application which used to work with the Google Maps API. I haven't changed the code since the last successful build but I am now unable to rebuild the app.

When I try to add a dependency to the "com.google.android.gms:play-service-maps:11.8.0" library, Android Studio tries to download the necessary files from the internet. Approximately when it reaches 50%, it displays the following error : "Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0".

Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve the problem?

Comment: have you checked your if your Api key is not updated?

Comment: Post your gradle. I had a similar problem.

Comment: As far as I understand the Api key, it only grants access to the maps data. Having a wrong key just leads to a blank screen instead of a detailed map. The problem can't be related to the Api key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0"`  to `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0`, app build was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the version from 11.8.0 to an older one. (11.0.2 for example)

Comment: In the "project structure" dialog box, in the "Dependencies" tab and in the list I get when I click on the "+", no other version for the maps library appears.

Comment: Just change it in the gradle file.

Comment: It is not. But at least you can build the app now.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services version depends on your `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle`

Try:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4
```

OR update your sdk version to the most recent.

Comment: My `compileSdkVersion` is "API 27".

Comment: use `11.0.4 `. My recent project was API 26

Comment: Tried to compile with `compileSdkVersion`set to 26 instead of 27 and `Build Tools Version`set to 26.0.2 instead of 27.0.1 and I get the same result.

Comment: please post your build.grade

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add dependency for Google Play services that are already specified in your Choose_Library_Dependency dialogue. This thing always worked for me. Just go through the options, you will find the match for Google Play services. Whatever the version specified there, you need to use the same in your google maps dependency.

[Screenshot](https://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/choose-library-dependency.png)

Comment: I use the following Google Play Service `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0`.